# How to unbox tuple?

Tags: c#, tuples, c#-7.0, unboxing

I have boxed tuple:

```
(int, string) tuple = (1, "abc");
object box = tuple;
```

How to obtain tuple from `box`? What is the right syntax to cast `object` back to tuple?

My attempt:

```
var deconstruct = (int, string)box;
```

is obviously wrong:

> Error CS1525  Invalid expression term 'int'
>
> Error CS1525  Invalid expression term 'string'
>
> Error CS1002  ; expected
>
> Error CS0201  Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Comment: have you tried (int, string) deconstruct = (int, string)box;

Comment: http://mustoverride.com/tuples_conversions/

Comment: The syntax of casts is `(type) expr`. The type of the tuple is `(int, string)`. Ergo: `((int, string)) box`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, after seeing the answer its obvious, I was somehow blinded by already having one set of bracers.

Comment: It's not the most readable syntax, even though it follows a logical pattern -- we can blame C for introducing that cast syntax in the first place (the tuple syntax seems fine).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
ValueTuple<int, string> t = (ValueTuple<int, string>)box;
```

or

```
(int, string) t = ((int, string))box;
```

Comment: Easy! One pair for the tuple, the other for the cast.